# How do I move some dependecies from require to require-dev with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

Some dependencies were mistakenly added to `require` instead of `require-dev`. I tried manually changing `composer.json` and running `composer install`, but `composer.lock` wasn't changed. So my guess is, that it ignored changes in `composer.json`, and just ensured that what's installed reflects what's in `composer.lock` file. Am I wrong here? If not wrong, how do I do that? I'd like to preserve versions of packages in `composer.lock` file as they are now as much as possible.

Comment: Have you got warnings after changing `composer.json` and running `composer install`?

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I just noticed the warning. But running `composer update` will update all dependencies (in other words, install newer versions where possible)? Can I avoid that?

Comment: I guess you can't. The only commands that seem to explicitly deal with `composer.lock` are `install` (installs dependencies from `composer.lock`, or generates a new lock file), `verify` (validates `composer.lock` and `composer.json`), and `update`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem and found a simple solution: `composer update`.

The following are the steps I have done.

**Old `composer.json`**

```
{
  "require": {
    "meenie/javascript-packer": "1.1"
  }
}

$ composer install
```

Saved a backup for `composer.lock` for further comparison:

```
$ cp composer.lock composer.lock-prev
```

**New `composer.json`**

```
{
  "require-dev": {
    "meenie/javascript-packer": "1.1"
  }
}


$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
```

I have updated Composer as the output above suggested:

```
$ composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Then looked at the differences between the old and new versions of `composer.lock`:

```
$ diff -Nau composer.lock-prev composer.lock 
--- composer.lock-prev  2016-10-29 19:05:51.331588329 +0700
+++ composer.lock   2016-10-29 19:06:05.639809116 +0700
@@ -4,9 +4,10 @@
         "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file",
         "This file is @generated automatically"
     ],
-    "hash": "f092e6d1418a7bb0db55b75f1099b4eb",
-    "content-hash": "774f074021977667a459f207616edfe2",
-    "packages": [
+    "hash": "0c81c48f9845635d47821bc0e965e4fe",
+    "content-hash": "cb194309c2a3fda3b07a46ed7ef36bdd",
+    "packages": [],
+    "packages-dev": [
         {
             "name": "meenie/javascript-packer",
             "version": "1.1",
@@ -45,7 +46,6 @@
             "time": "2013-03-25 21:54:33"
         }
     ],
-    "packages-dev": [],
     "aliases": [],
     "minimum-stability": "stable",
     "stability-flags": [],
```

We can see that the changes are actually applied after running `composer update`.

Comment: Doesn't this risk changing versions of libraries, too?

Comment: @Chris, particularly `dev-master` is always a risk. Do you mean I should rather show a sample with fixed versions? I've updated the answer. I believe there is no risk regarding versions as long as only fixed versions are used.

Comment: What you're missing here is, say, I required `phpunit` a year ago, and let's assume it was `phpunit-5.5.7` back then. And in `composer.json` I had `"phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5"`. Now I realized it's in `require` section. I moved it to `require-dev`, ran `composer update`, and now I have `phpunit-5.6.2`. Isn't it? That's what I'd like to avoid, if possible.

Comment: @x-yuri, then use more stable dependency versions like `"5.5"`. Also, moving dependencies from release to development is rather safe, if the production actually doesn't need these dependencies, isn't it? So you can simply replace your `^.5.5` constraint with `5.5`, and you'll have `5.5` installed after `composer install` or `composer update`

Comment: Indeed, in my case it doesn't matter much. As for `5.5` version specification, it's not more stable, it's as stable as it gets. Anyways, I was looking for what to `ruby` programmers is [Conservative Updating](https://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-install.1.html#CONSERVATIVE-UPDATING). It seems the one doesn't exist in `php` world.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, I mean what I think the OP is asking about: the question is how to move a dependency from `require` to `require-dev` without changing any versions. I think this solution satisfies the first part of that, but not the second.

Answer (score 28):

I would do:

```
composer require --dev drupal/devel
```

or for your example

```
composer require --dev meenie/javascript-packer:1.1
```

which makes composer do all the heavy lifting and moves those dependencies into the require-dev section.

Comment: Worked perfectly for the situation described in the question

Comment: Easy and simple no fuss thanks

Answer (score 11):

It seems that `composer update --lock` can solve your problem.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! I just changed the placement (moved from require-dev to require in composer.json) and ran this. I think this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

in composer, version 2 at least, if you run the command again with --dev it promp if you want to move it acordently. Oposite example, if you got the dependency in dev and want to move to required `composer install doctrine/dbal` will prompt;

> doctrine/dbal is currently present in the require-dev key and you ran
> the command without the --dev flag, which will move it to the require
> key. Do you want to move this requirement? [no]? yes